# How to change an HTML element content

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So, the title makes this seem easier than it really is. I am developing a memory game for an online JavaScript course project which has some starter code to begin with.

I am trying to update the counter display in the HTML and have tried every possible method I know to do so but have been unsuccessful so far. The element is defined as an HTML collection and I have no idea why....it is a simple integer. I am sure I am missing something simple, can anyone point out what it is?

The current code is located at [GitHub](https://github.com/shayghc/memory-game)

Comment: Please do not post content (especially code) from external sites.  Put the code in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('the-element-id').innerHTML = 'new content';
```

i hope this will help

Comment: Even if this answer does solve the OP's problem, I would advise to use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`. (I am not going to downvote you for this). The latter one has more drawbacks than the former. There are circumstances where using `.innerHMTL` is justified. Which is not the case of the circumstance that the OP has described. For more info, please check the duplicate link.

Comment: Excellent! The issue is that I was using `<target>.innerHTML('<text>');` instead of `<target>.innerHTML = '<text>';`